# React Native 401 Unauthorized Error From DRF

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, heroku, axios

My restful api (Django Rest API) on heroku works fine locally. It's currently deployed on heroku. I'm using react native app to interact with the API.

Each time i try retrieving the details of authenticated user, first the details is returned just after that it throws 401 error....

The flow of my application is

- After successful authentication
- Save user's token
- Retrieve authenticated user's details

Authentication passes fine (authenticated user's details is also outputted on the log) but the bit of getting user's details fails with 401 unauthorized

Here is my server log on heroku

```sh
2020-12-21T22:33:45.106941+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:33:45 +0000] "POST /api/accounts/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 441 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"

2020-12-21T22:33:45.232882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT path="/api/accounts/token/device/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=4a5a06f9-ec50-4ecb-879e-20805784ba5c fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=255 protocol=https

2020-12-21T22:33:45.106757+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/accounts/token/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a4b7e5f6-1333-4b82-b180-12850391c382 fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=399ms status=200 bytes=724 protocol=https

2020-12-21T22:33:45.232905+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:33:45 +0000] "PUT /api/accounts/token/device/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"

2020-12-21T22:33:45.368821+00:00 app[web.1]: Unauthorized: /api/users/details/

2020-12-21T22:33:45.369671+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:33:45 +0000] "GET /api/users/details/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"
2020-12-21T22:33:45.369458+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/users/details/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=1de46c11-fa6d-4ebd-984e-40191239f031 fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=401 bytes=393 protocol=https


NOTICE THIS BIT HERE ( Which shows that the user is authorized )


2020-12-21T22:33:45.587452+00:00 app[web.1]:  26 
2020-12-21T22:33:45.587453+00:00 app[web.1]: False
2020-12-21T22:33:45.595378+00:00 app[web.1]: Below is the serializer response 
2020-12-21T22:33:45.595436+00:00 app[web.1]:  {'pk': 15, 'first_name': 'Test', 'middle_name': '', 'last_name': 'Ysgs', 'image': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxx&Signature=l4fHz7c%xxxxxxxx%3D&Expires=xxxxxxx', 'pref_address': None, 'can_request_delivery': True, 'account_type': 'Standard Account', 'phone_number': '+09082983928392', 'email': 'Aass@mail.com'} 


2020-12-21T22:33:45.596414+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:33:45 +0000] "GET /api/users/details/ HTTP/1.1" 200 395 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"
2020-12-21T22:33:45.596171+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/users/details/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d4c8a812-b9e0-4fb9-a273-5697af4513c4 fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=683 protocol=https

2020-12-21T22:34:15.197708+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:34:15 +0000] "POST /api/accounts/token/ HTTP/1.1" 200 441 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"

2020-12-21T22:34:15.341847+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:34:15 +0000] "PUT /api/accounts/token/device/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"

2020-12-21T22:34:15.197578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/accounts/token/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a33bddd3-b942-4126-95a4-18c36a722afe fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=230ms status=200 bytes=724 protocol=https

2020-12-21T22:34:15.347870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT path="/api/accounts/token/device/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=28c0951c-3252-4a78-84b5-34b1609c8e42 fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=200 bytes=255 protocol=https

2020-12-21T22:34:15.550870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/users/details/" host=webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c91941ef-cc54-4df9-bc44-56a5cf4e2839 fwd="86.182.91.70" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=401 bytes=393 protocol=https




NOTICE THIS BIT HERE ( automatically makes says user is unauthorized )

2020-12-21T22:34:15.550059+00:00 app[web.1]: Unauthorized: /api/users/details/

2020-12-21T22:34:15.550879+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.43.233.181 - - [21/Dec/2020:22:34:15 +0000] "GET /api/users/details/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58 "-" "jisee/1 CFNetwork/1206 Darwin/20.1.0"
```

ON my xCode, i get this on my log

```sh
2020-12-21 22:48:46.780760+0000 jisee[7365:1567414] [javascript] { [Error: Request failed with status code 401]
  config: 
   { url: 'https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details',
     method: 'get',
     headers: 
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
        Authorization: 'Bearer my-token-ViZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTYInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTY' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function] ],
     timeout: 0,
     adapter: [Function],
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     maxBodyLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
     data: undefined },
  request: 
   { UNSENT: 0,
     OPENED: 1,
     HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
     LOADING: 3,
     DONE: 4,
     readyState: 4,
     status: 401,
     timeout: 0,
     withCredentials: true,
     upload: {},
     _aborted: false,
     _hasError: false,
     _method: 'GET',
     _perfKey: 'network_XMLHttpRequest_https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details',
     _response: '{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}',
     _url: 'https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details',
     _timedOut: false,
     _trackingName: 'unknown',
     _incrementalEvents: false,
     responseHeaders: 
      { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Www-Authenticate': 'Bearer realm="api"',
        Via: '1.1 vegur',
        Date: 'Mon, 21 Dec 2020 22:48:46 GMT',
        'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin',
        Server: 'gunicorn/20.0.4',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Allow: 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
        'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
        Vary: 'Accept, Origin',
        'Content-Length': '58',
        'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY' },
     _requestId: null,
     _cachedResponse: undefined,
     _headers: 
      { accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
        authorization: 'Bearer my-token-ViZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTYNjc3MzI2LCJqdGkiOiI2Mjk4ZWFkNjAxZTE0NGNhYTljOWNmMjAwYTUwNDViZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTY' },
     _responseType: '',
     _sent: true,
     _lowerCaseResponseHeaders: 
      { 'content-type': 'application/json',
        'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="api"',
        via: '1.1 vegur',
        date: 'Mon, 21 Dec 2020 22:48:46 GMT',
        'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
        server: 'gunicorn/20.0.4',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        allow: 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        vary: 'Accept, Origin',
        'content-length': '58',
        'x-frame-options': 'DENY' },
     _subscriptions: [],
     responseURL: 'https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details/' },
  response: 
   { data: { detail: 'Authentication credentials were not provided.' },
     status: 401,
     statusText: undefined,
     headers: 
      { 'content-type': 'application/json',
        'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="api"',
        via: '1.1 vegur',
        date: 'Mon, 21 Dec 2020 22:48:46 GMT',
        'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
        server: 'gunicorn/20.0.4',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        allow: 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        vary: 'Accept, Origin',
        'content-length': '58',
        'x-frame-options': 'DENY' },
     config: 
      { url: 'https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details',
        method: 'get',
        headers: 
         { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
           Authorization: 'Bearer my-token-ViZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTYl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjA4Njc3MzI2LCJqdGkiOiI2Mjk4ZWFkNjAxZTE0NGNhYTljOWNmMjAwYTUwNDViZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTY' },
        transformRequest: [ [Function] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function] ],
        timeout: 0,
        adapter: [Function],
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        maxBodyLength: -1,
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        data: undefined },
     request: 
      { UNSENT: 0,
        OPENED: 1,
        HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
        LOADING: 3,
        DONE: 4,
        readyState: 4,
        status: 401,
        timeout: 0,
        withCredentials: true,
        upload: {},
        _aborted: false,
        _hasError: false,
        _method: 'GET',
        _perfKey: 'network_XMLHttpRequest_https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details',
        _response: '{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}',
        _url: 'https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details',
        _timedOut: false,
        _trackingName: 'unknown',
        _incrementalEvents: false,
        responseHeaders: 
         { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Www-Authenticate': 'Bearer realm="api"',
           Via: '1.1 vegur',
           Date: 'Mon, 21 Dec 2020 22:48:46 GMT',
           'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin',
           Server: 'gunicorn/20.0.4',
           Connection: 'keep-alive',
           Allow: 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
           'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
           Vary: 'Accept, Origin',
           'Content-Length': '58',
           'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY' },
        _requestId: null,
        _cachedResponse: undefined,
        _headers: 
         { accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
           authorization: 'Bearer my-token-ViZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjI2fQ.3-xy4vMiqa4qCiCC6nD3lQY6_-GXv-ARau2HbfTTY' },
        _responseType: '',
        _sent: true,
        _lowerCaseResponseHeaders: 
         { 'content-type': 'application/json',
           'www-authenticate': 'Bearer realm="api"',
           via: '1.1 vegur',
           date: 'Mon, 21 Dec 2020 22:48:46 GMT',
           'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
           server: 'gunicorn/20.0.4',
           connection: 'keep-alive',
           allow: 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
           'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
           vary: 'Accept, Origin',
           'content-length': '58',
           'x-frame-options': 'DENY' },
        _subscriptions: [],
        responseURL: 'https://webapp.herokuapp.com/api/users/details/' } },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function] }
```

API URL CONSTRUCT

```py
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import views as apiview


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', apiview.UserViewSet)


app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

## API VIEW CODE

```py
class UserViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    """Contains set of views that processes request to manipulate
    user's data
    """
    model = User
    look_up_field = 'pk'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    parser_classes = [
        parsers.MultiPartParser,
        parsers.FormParser,
        parsers.JSONParser,
    ]
    permission_class_kwargs = {
        "list":(permissions.IsAuthenticated,custom_perms.IsOperationStaff,),
        "create": (permissions.AllowAny, ),
        "retrieve":(permissions.IsAuthenticated, ),
        "destroy": (permissions.IsAuthenticated, custom_perms.IsMyAccount,),
        "update": (permissions.IsAuthenticated, custom_perms.IsMyAccount,)
    }
    
    @action(
        detail=False,
        methods=['GET'],
        url_name='details',
        url_path='details',
        permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    )            
    def details(self, request):
        """Returns the details of authenticated user account"""
        print("\n\n\n", request.user.pk, "\n\n\n\n")
        print(request.user.pk == None)
        print("\n\n\n\n\n")
        

        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user.me)
        print("Below is the serializer response \n\n\n",
            serializer.data, "\n\n\n\n\n\n")
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Below are my requirements

```
react-native: "0.63.3",      
axios: "^0.21.0",
Django==3.1.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
djangorestframework==3.11.1
djangorestframework-gis==0.16
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.3.0
```

**OBSERVATION**

I can make request using postman client, cURLs, python request to same endpoint on heroku server, and will get a valid response (Never experienced 401 unauthorized from the mentioned clients)

Please how do i resolve this issue ?

## EDITED (EDIT 01)

Add my restful api view that outputs the details of the authenticated user

## Edited (Edit 02)

==================

I manually create token for users as there are various account type, each authentication is different. Below is how i handle the authentication piece

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    fb_token = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password'] = PasswordField()
        self.fields['phone'] = serializers.CharField(required=False)
        self.fields['email'] = serializers.CharField(required=False)
        self.fields['fb_token'] = serializers.CharField(required=False)
        self.user = None

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        return token

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """Validates provided incredentials for authentication. 

        Provides mechanism to authenticate through phone and email.
        For phone authentication, firebase token is needed to fully 
        authenticate the request. Password not required here

        For email authentication, request will only be validated if
        a valid and existent email and password is provided.

        If invalid credentials are passed, authentication will fail.
        """
        auth_type = auth_services.check_auth_type(attrs)
        if type(auth_type) is str:
            
            if auth_type == "phone":
                tokens_or_none = auth_services.phone_auth_service(
                    phone=attrs.get('phone'), fb_token=attrs.get('fb_token'),
                    request=self.context.get('request', None),
                )
                return tokens_or_none

            elif auth_type == "email":
                return super().validate(attrs)

        return auth_type
```

Answer (score 0):

To list user info you have permissions:

```py
"list":(permissions.IsAuthenticated,custom_perms.IsOperationStaff,),
```

Is your user `OperationStaff`?

Comment: For the tested scenario, the user isn't an OperationStaff. On the defined action decorator, the custom view also has it's own `permission_classes` which automatically overrides the class configuration ```The decorator allows you to override any viewset-level configuration such as permission_classes, serializer_class, filter_backends...:``` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: In authorization header you have: `Bearer my-token-ViZCIsInVz....` is it ok to add `my-token`? Do you have custom token creation?

Comment: Yes i manually create my tokens as i've different user account and each authenticates using different process. For example usersTypeOne token is created after successful phone auth validation while userTypeTwo token is created after successful email & password authentication

Comment: I updated my Question showing how i manually handle token creation

Comment: OK, I see that you are able to send requests to the server from other sources. You see the error when sending requests from React.  Can you post React code which you use for sending requests? And maybe your application settings? It is hard to debug the code without full code ... Maybe put it in the repo?